# Align popover on clicked position React antd

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd, popover

```
<Popover 
  visible={visible} 
  content={content} 
  overlayInnerStyle={{ borderRadius: "8px", textAlign: "center" }} 
  placement="top"
>  
  <div
    className="example-div"
    id={exampleId}
    contentEditable="true"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styledExample }}
    onClick={this.onHandleClick}
  />
</Popover>
```

Here `Popover` visibility has been managed using state.
I have added `placement="top"`, as the div size is 100%, so  `Popover` is getting populated on top middle of the div.

How can i align `Popover` placement exactly at clicked place instead of top middle.